# How to redirect a user from winform to ASP.Net webpage?

Tags: html, winforms

Hey there i am working on a project where a user needs to register himself from a winform. Now i need to redirect the user to a ASP.Net web page or a Html page but i cannot find a way to do that, i tried to make an object of html file but it was giving an error, Is there any way for doing this.
Thanks

Comment: Do you want to redirect to a specific url?

Comment: I have an index.html page and i just want to redirect the user to that index page

Comment: See the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use LinkLable for that. Just set LinkLable text to your url. Try this :

```
private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(linkLabel1.Text); // It will go to the url address with your default browser
    }
```

Or if you have WebBrowser in your form you can try this code :

```
private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.Navigate(linkLabel1.Text);
    }
```